# Не знаю как поставить объекты(3 textarea, 1 button) в строку

Tags: html, css

[image: Эти все части должны стоять в строчку.]

Эти все части должны стоять в строчку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для блока в котором находятся элементы

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: flex почему-то не ставит это все дело в столбик. Пытался максимально сделать с помощью flex`a, но как понимаю усилий не хватило.

Comment: если нужно в столбик то добавьте ещё flex-direction: column;